# Change font color and shadow from titlebar in window manager

Tags: window-manager, colors, xfce, fonts

I'm trying Linux Mint Debian Edition XFCE, and want to use a specific theme; only drawback - the font color and font shadow are unreadable, how can I change them?
Also the active/inactive color window separation is very hard to distinguish.
I added a screenshot for demonstration.
[image]
(seems that stackexchange doesn't zooms in the image when clicking, so you have to use the "right-click>view image" option, I apologize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to copy the theme from "/usr/share/themes/**themename**/gtkrc"  to `$HOME/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and modify it. Please see [xfwm4 theme guide on the xfce wiki](http://wiki.xfce.org/howto/xfwm4_theme).

(1) Shadow,

> **Text shadow**
>
> A shadow can be added to the title text by setting the boolean value
>   “`title_shadow_active`” for the focused window, and
>   “`title_shadow_inactive`” for the other unfocused windows.
>
> Possible values are “false”, “true”, and “frame”.

(2) Titelbar decorations,

> For title bar decorations, xfwm4 uses 5 pixmaps named
>   `title-1-active.xpm` to `title-5-active.xpm` with `top-left-active.xpm` and
>   `top-right-active.xpm` making up the corners on each end as per figure 2
>   below.

Answer (score 3):

For others with the same problem. Go to window manager and select the same theme that you selected in Appearance. This way the style of the window title would match the overall color scheme.

Comment: You're a saver!

Comment: That was not the most intuitive solution :P

Comment: Also, not all themes have a matching one in window manager. E.g. I use Dust Sand and don't see it.