# Hard to read and non visible UI elements under XFCE with dark themes

Tags: xfce, colors, fonts, accessibility

I am using XUbuntu 20.04 (XFCE 4.14) and have selected Greybird-dark style and theme which are in tune with my low light environment setup that I have found to be easier on my eyes.  However, some UI elements are hard to read and others are just non-visible.

The first element was the font shadow which was removed by following the accepted answer in [Change font color and shadow from titlebar in window manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42781).  In my case the issue resulted from having Greybird-dark style selected under Appearance with Greybird under Window Manager.  Fortunately, Window Manager does include a Greybird-dark theme and selecting it took care of the non-readable ugly font shadow from window titles.

Now, as can be seen in the following images, dividers are either difficult to see (requiring adjusting my display brightness to a very high setting, something I want to avoid in the first place) or just non-visible (no brightness setting helps).

XFCE panel:

[image: XFCE panel using a dark theme]

Firefox tabs:

[image: Firefox tabs using a dark theme]

Not being able to distinguish those UI elements  not only makes common tasks like switching workspace and tabs (file manager, browser, etc.) using the mouse a rather unpleasant, difficult and thus frustrating experience, but my eyes get tired really soon.

So the first question is how to adjust the color of separators in XFCE panels.  A lighter color may improve contrast without adjusting the brightness on my display.  Same for tabs under Thunar & Firefox (I am guessing that both elements may be based on the same setting).

Changing the background color of the selected tab could help as well as the current gray forces me to adjust the brightness (even if not to such a high setting as the separators require).

And the second question or thought is in regards to appropriate colors for dark themes that make easier to identify those elements while keeping the display under low brightness (which is easier on my eyes for spending long hours in front of a computer display).

The dark-theme idea is very recent and experimentation lead us to find the settings that best suite those like myself with reduced vision after some 35 years of burning our eyes using bright displays with white background (a long debate in itself as you may already know).